# How to convert any periodic signal to a square wave signal using the Schmitt Trigger?

Tags: signal, converter, trigger, square

I had to make a kind of frequency meter, and what made me stuck was the signal formatting. I couldn’t build a circuit containing the Schmitt Trigger, which will allow me to convert any periodic signal into a square wave signal afterwards. Because I will need this type of signal which will trigger a binary counter that only works if there is a square wave signal (pulses).
Here is a blueprint of this frequency meter:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your question to show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with any schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Comment: What is the frequency range, the amplitude and the DC component of the input signal?

Comment: First be clear about your requirements. If by "square wave" you mean a duty cycle close to 50%, a Schmitt trigger alone won't do it for arbitrary periodic waveform inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Use a series capacitor before schmitt trigger to remove offset and go to pulse counter.
(If you need more detailed answer you need to add schematics or some other information)